# Issue with installing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework in portable class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, portable-class-library

I am trying to install 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' in a portable class library but getting the following error.

---

> **Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.0' does not exist in project 'PortableLib' Install-Package : Failed to add reference to
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'. Please make sure that it is
>
> ### > in the Global Assembly Cache.At line:1 char:1

Is there anything equivalent to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' package that I can use with PCL? 
Any help greatly appreciated.